# User Management with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a background in Django but I've never used a CMS before. I have been given this task at my company to use wordpress to make a website. The website needs to support user registration via standard sign up / sign in process which redirects the user to a his own profile page where he can interact with the web app. This is easily possible in Django but I'm not allowed to use anything apart from PHP. I decided to use a CMS as the site contains a lot of webpages with simple text content, not to mention the host of nice themes available for PHP. It is possible to do this in Wordpress or should I just look for a web framework in php and get on with it?

Thanks

Comment: There are plenty of good plugins in the [Repository](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/) and nice articles all around the blogosphere. You can research [WordPress StackExchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2B%22user+registration%22+%2Bplugin) archives, but note that plugin recommendation is off-topic over there.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has a registration system for different roles (admin,editor,author,subscriber etc.). You can use its native functions to test [**if**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in) a user is logged in and [**which**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo) user is logged in, and display the relevant data accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit wp-login.php.

Find the case 'login' :
and change the else of
    $redirect_to = admin_url();

to

```
$redirect_to = admin_url(). "/profile.php";
```

However, I am not sure you want to make a habit of editing wp-login.php as when you update it might cause problems or be overwritten.  There is most likely more elegant ways to do that, or write a function to do it.

As far as plugins go, I have used s2Member to redirect users on login to a different page of my selection, even based on roles.  I don't see why you couldn't change to the profile and not cause any hacking issues mentioned above.

Looking back there are older plugins and a few mentions on google that I could find, so it is possible.  Don't give up on WordPress so fast, there are plugins for just about anything you can think of.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [login_redirect](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect) filter to change the page the user sees upon login.

Get familiar with using [action and filter hooks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API) to do things in WordPress. They are your friends :)